# Getting a strange error when Try to save a SSRS report

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, memory-management, ssrs-2008

Hi I have created a report in SSRS and I have been saving changes as I was building the report now right before the end I made a few more changes and now when I try to save the report it gives me this error message "Attemped to read aor write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt", any idea what is going on any suggestions please ??? [image]

Additional Information about the machine I am working on, Windows 7,  SQL Server 2008 R2 , and SSRS 2008 R2, I have 12GB Ram, and some 3.5Ghz Processor. Cant really see how its getting short of Memory from anywhere ??? Any Advise please

Comment: Maybe it's actually a hardware problem?

Comment: @AaronBertrand before this report I created about 6 reports made changes to a couple and then all of sudden this happens.

Comment: Have you been editing the RDL source file specifically?

Comment: @IanPreston Nope not touched it.

Comment: Hmm, this has happened to me, and I feel like it was when I was editing the report source while I also had the report open in Design mode in another tab. Since I stopped doing that I haven't experienced the error. Sorry this didn't help your specific case. When it did occur I just saved the reports and restarted Visual Studio with no ill effects. But it's a super annoying error for sure.

Comment: @IanPreston I am looking for some sort of solution for this problem will post if I find something, In my case I cant even save the changes and I have done a lot of work on this report so I am hoping I will not have to restart the whole thing, dont want to redo all the work again :(

Comment: @IanPreston Have a look and be amazed what solved the issue lol

Comment: This happens to me after I go to View Code and save changes there. It's just a warning, it still saves. Just close and reopen to make it go away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it and believe me or not this solved the issue, found this solution online

> I got the same error while working with VS 2008 Sp1 on some WPF
>   project. The message:   "Attempted to read or write protected memory.
>   This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt." appeared.
>
> I think it's caused by the window layout system of visual studio. I
>   had the solution view and output view parked on another monitor.
>
> After "Reset Windows Layout" the problem dissapeared.   Robert

Its working fine now :)

Comment: "Reset Windows Layout" is found under the "Windows" menu, in case you're wondering like I was