# Attempted to read or write protected memory-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to save a view in sql-server management studio which brings the following error message

*Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt*

The same query works fine if I run it separately.

The full error message is below

```
===================================

Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.DataTools.Interop)

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.DataTools.Interop.IDTDocTool.Save(Object dsRef, String path, Boolean okToOverwrite)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.ViewDesignerNode.Save(VSSAVEFLAGS dwSave, String strSilentSaveAsName, IVsUIShell pIVsUIShell, IntPtr punkDocDataIntPtr, String& strMkDocumentNew, Int32& pfCanceled)
```

I am not sure where to look at

Comment: Tried restarting management studio?

Comment: Yes, I did couple of times but the same result. If I click the execute sql option, SSMS get crashed. It says `APPCRASH`

Comment: [Quite a few of these on Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/SearchResults.aspx?KeywordSearchIn=2&SearchQuery=%22Attempted%20to%20read%20or%20write%20protected%20memory%22&FeedbackType=1&Scope=0&SortOrder=10&TabView=0#&&PageIndex=1). Top voted one indicates that a conflicting VS install might be to blame. Though [others were product bugs](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/330069/subselect-query-in-a-view-crashes-ssms)

Comment: @MartinSmith: Thanks Martin, its definitely something to do with designer. I tried creating the view using `CREATE VIEW ViewName AS ...` which created it

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message a few days back working on some reports on BIDS and strangely enough just resetting the windows layout fixed the issue. Because I had `Solution Explorer` sitting on a separate monitor.

While I was looking for a solution for this problem online I came across cases where people were getting this error message because of the other software installed on their machine.

There is no `One` reason for this error but hopefully this is a good place to start from. resetting the windows layout can you believe this :)

Question I asked a few weeks ago and didnt get any answers [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20117066/getting-a-strange-error-when-try-to-save-a-ssrs-report)

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same error message while trying to edit top rows. But manual query works fine.

[image]

**Reason behind:**

1. I already installed SQL Server Management 2012.
2. Then i installed SQL Server Management 2018.
3. I opened SSMS from 2012 where we faced the above mentioned issue.
4. Later opened SSMS 2018, then problem got rectified.