# Query Designer in VS 2010 causes Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, query-designer

I have a problem calling the query designer in visual studio 2010. My shared datasource points to an local SQL Server 2012 with an simple Test-Database containing one table. When i want to open the query designer i get the following problem:

[image]

After clicking the OK button the query designer opens in text edit mode, but i need the graphic mode for a presentation on monday. Already reinstalled Visual Studi 2010 but still getting this error. Can somebody please help?

Details of the message

```
===================================

Object reference not set to an instance of an object. (Microsoft Visual Studio)

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.QueryDesigners.InternalQueryDesignerWrapper.InitializeDesigner()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.QueryDesigners.InternalQueryDesignerWithGenericModeWrapper.Initialize()
```

Comment: I had a similar issue with Visual Studio a few months ago have a look here [`Getting a strange error when Try to save a SSRS report`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20117066/getting-a-strange-error-when-try-to-save-a-ssrs-report) and be amazed what solved the issue :)

Comment: I also found that solution and tried it by Window --> Reset Window Layout in Visual Studio but the error still occures

Comment: have tried resetting windows layout and close VS and restart it again?

Comment: Yes. But the error still occures... it drives me crazy...

Comment: Sorry mate, I couldn't find any solution for it either and the only thing that fixed it, really isn't a solution or fix, I reckon log a bug on [`Microsoft Connect`](https://connect.microsoft.com/).